# Apply CSS only to a specific page based on link

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file that prints different categories based on the link (GET), this html file has a global CSS file assigned to it, so all categories look the same.

I want to make a specific category look different, adjust the width of the content and other things, is there any way to apply the CSS style only to a specific category without altering every other?

Actual CSS Code of all categories/page:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
    body { min-width:100%; }
    [layout="sp-layout-fixed"] { width:100%; }
    #sp-index-navigation { display:none !important; }
    #sp-sky,
    #sp-header,
    #sp-category-1-normal { background:#fff; }
    #sp-category-1-normal > ul { white-space:nowrap; margin:0 60px;}
    .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul { margin:30px 0 0 0; }
    .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li { width:32%; margin-left:0; overflow:hidden; }
    .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li + li { margin-left:2%; }
    .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] .sp-slider[between="30"] .slick-slide { margin:0 !important; }
    #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-description ul li.sp-left { width:50%; }
    #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-content > ul > li { padding:30px !important; }
}
```

HTML code of the page:

```
<div id="sp-project" layout="sp-layout-fixed" module="Project_Package">
    <div id="{$cate_id}" class="sp-project-loop" module="project_list">
        CATEGORIES CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

The URL look like: somesite . com/page.html?cat=123

I wanted that for example, when I open somesite . com/page.html?cat=444, instead this CSS code is used instead of the other:

```
@media screen and (max-width:3500px){
        body { min-width:100%; }
        [layout="sp-layout-fixed"] { width:80%; margin: 0 auto; }
        #sp-index-navigation { display:none !important; }
        #sp-sky,
        #sp-header,
        #sp-category-1-normal { background:#fff; }
        #sp-category-1-normal > ul { white-space:nowrap; margin:0 60px;}
        .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul { margin:30px 0 0 0; }
        .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li { width:32%; margin-left:0; overflow:hidden; }
        .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li + li { margin-left:2%; }
        .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] .sp-slider[between="30"] .slick-slide { margin:0 !important; }
        #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-description ul li.sp-left { width:50%; }
        #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-content > ul > li { padding:30px !important; }
}
```

Is there any way to override the CSS code and use a different CSS based on which ?cat=ID is used on the link?

Comment: Not with CSS alone. Is your server able to update the markup that gets rendered for `page.html?cat=444`?

Comment: @ksav I do not know that, as I cannot modify the server side/root, because my website is hosted on a third-party service, at the moment I can only modify HTML and CSS files

Comment: If you can edit HTML files, add a class to the document body for each `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two CSS classes, each of them is for styling each page.
Then you can use Javascript to detect what current page is, and set the needed CSS class (1 of those 2 above) to the 'body' element of your page.

The code below will detect if the current page is ...com/page.html?cat=444 or not, then add the CSS class to the 'body' element if true:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/page.html?cat=444') >= 0) {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('page-444');
}
```

The code below is modified from your code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:3500px){
        .page-444 body { min-width:100%; }
        .page-444 [layout="sp-layout-fixed"] { width:80%; margin: 0 auto; }
        .page-444 #sp-index-navigation { display:none !important; }
        .page-444 #sp-sky,
        .page-444 #sp-header,
        .page-444 #sp-category-1-normal { background:#fff; }
        .page-444 #sp-category-1-normal > ul { white-space:nowrap; margin:0 60px;}
        .page-444 .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul { margin:30px 0 0 0; }
        .page-444 .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li { width:32%; margin-left:0; overflow:hidden; }
        .page-444 .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] > ul > li + li { margin-left:2%; }
        .page-444 .sp-index-point-1[grid="3"] .sp-slider[between="30"] .slick-slide { margin:0 !important; }
        .page-444 #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-description ul li.sp-left { width:50%; }
        .page-444 #sp-footer-design-3 .sp-footer-content > ul > li { padding:30px !important; }
}
```

Yes, it looks ugly because you have to repeat the css class multiple times. But SASS/SCSS can help! (nested CSS class).

Comment: Can you show the code for detecting what the current page is, and then setting the CSS class?

Comment: I thought about that, but, doesn't that implies that the class is a single one to apply? inside the @media in CSS I have a bunch of classes, not just one

Comment: @marcoromano I have modified my answer, please tell me if you need to change anything. Thanks!